# $10$ identical black balls, $5$ identical red balls, $2$ identical white balls. What is the probability of choosing three black balls from this box?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have $10$ identical black balls, $5$ identical red balls, $2$ identical white balls in my box. What is the probability of choosing three black balls from this box?

**My Attempt:** We have to first consider each ball is different and the points in the sample space is ${17} \choose 3$.

We can choose three black balls in ${10} \choose 3$  ways. So the probability is $\frac{{10} \choose 3}{{17} \choose 3}$

Can anyone please check my attempt ?

Comment: The question should mention "in three draws", *then* it is correct.

Comment: @trueblueanil This solution is for 1 draw of three balls, at the same time, or three consecutive draws without replacement. But that's how I interpret it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes, I agree, the solution is right for such a question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct, **if** you draw the three balls without putting them back. To be even clearer, you can also write the solution this way:
$$\frac{\binom{10}{3}\binom{5}{0}\binom{2}{0}}{\binom{17}{3}} = \frac{\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{17}{3}}$$